# CSS float left and under an image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position the div id #left underneath my image.  Unfortunately, the two keep getting stuck on top of each other. 

How do I fix this?  The #left div has to be a fixed position.

In case you want to run it to see how it looks:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>iSignout</title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrapCSS.css"/>
     <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"

  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="http://businessgross.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Employee.png">
    <br>

    <div id="left">
            <h3 id=add>Add An Employee</h3>
            <form>
                <label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="firstName"><br>
                <label for="lastName">Last Name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="lastName"><br>
                <label for="phone">Phone Number: </label>
                <input type="tel" name="phone"><br>
                <label for="email">E-Mail: </label>
                <input type="email" name="email"><br>
                <input type="button" value="Add" id="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>

    <!--Creates the tables with employees -->
    <div id='center'>
        <table class= 'table table-hover'>
            <thead>
                <tr id="title"><th colspan=3>People In the Office</th></tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            <!--Create rows here -->
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th class>IN/OUT Status</th>
                    <th>Optional Note</th>
                </tr>

                <tr id= "peter-griffin">
                    <td>
                        <a href="#openModal">Peter Griffin</a>

                            <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
                                <div>
                                    <a href="#close" title="Close" id='modalClose' class="close">X</a>
                                    <h2>Peter Griffin</h2>
                                        <p>Phone:123-456-7890.</p>
                                        <p>email: petergriffin@gmail.com</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        <input type='radio' name="Peterpresent">In<br>
                        <input type='radio' name="Peterpresent">Out
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" id='del' class="close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        <textarea placeholder="Optional Note about where your are or your schedule"></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


    <!-- start: Delete Coupon Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Warning!</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                 <h4> Are you sure you want to DELETE?</h4>

            </div>
            <!--/modal-body-collapse -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btnDelteYes" href="#">Yes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </div>
            <!--/modal-footer-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap_script.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}


.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

fomr > label {
    clear:left;
    text-align:right;
    padding-bottom: .25em;
}

body {
    background-image:url('http://automobilein.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Background-Wallpaper-Hd.jpg');
    }

#left {
    display:inline-block;
    position:fixed;
    float:left;
    border:3px solid black;
    background-color: #B20000;
    margin-left: 2em;
    padding: .5em;
}


#center  {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:40%;
    padding:3em;
    text-align:center;
}

img {
    height: 20%;
    width:20%;
    position: absolute;
    top:1em;
    left:1em;
}
```

Comment: You have some open HTML code (link to Bootstrap source needs to be closed). Can you provide a fiddle? We don't know what your custom CSS looks like.

Comment: the div nor the image have z-indexes on them, so they're going to show up in whatever order the browser decides they should.

Comment: should have thought of that sooner http://jsfiddle.net/CJ9Mv/

Comment: r u expecting like this ? - http://jsfiddle.net/CJ9Mv/1/

Comment: That works, but is there a way I can vertically center it underneath the image?

Comment: Depends on what you're going for. Did you want your #left form to stay directly beneath the picture even when resizing the window? Or is it okay that when you scroll through the window, the form moves away from the picture?

Comment: Its fine, I'll just position it with the top offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the top offset of your `#left` div like this:

```
#left {
  top: 60px;
}
```

Checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cTjvB/)

Comment: I am trying to vertically center #left underneath the image

Comment: Why not use `absolute` positioning instead of `fixed` then? Because if you do so you will always have a gap when you scroll. You could also insert the image into the popup ?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
margin-top:5em;
```

in your #left css

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CJ9Mv/1/)